# Resize table size

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I created a table insight `FlowPane`.

```
flowPane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1)
    {
        double value = (double) t1;
        table.setPrefSize(value, 600);
        System.out.println("Scene Width :" + value);
    }
});
```

I want when I resize the main stage and also the `FlowPane` also to resize the size of the table. I created this listener which takes the `FlowPane` size. But when I resize the the main stage the table size is not changed. Can you help me what I'm missing?

Comment: why do you want to use Flowpane to just put one table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only updating the width of the table in the changed method of your listener I'm going to assume that you only want the table to grow/shrink horizontally. Assuming this is the case, I would suggest that rather than setting up a *ChangeListener*, you try setting up a unidirectional binding between the width properties of the the FlowPane and the TableView.

```
table.prefWidthProperty().bind(flowPane.widthProperty());
```

The binding ensures that anytime the flowPane's *widthProperty* changes, the table's *prefWidthProperty* will also be updated. If you wish to continue using the *ChangeListener*, you can avoid casting the new value as follows...

```
flowPane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Number t, Number t1)
    {
        table.setPrefSize(t1.doubleValue(), 600);
        System.out.println("Scene Width :" + t1.doubleValue());
    }
});
```

Hope this answer is helpful!